# Набор текстов для изучающего русский язык

Tags: общие-вопросы, обучение

Мой знакомый американец не знает что ему читать, чтобы развивать свой русский. Детские сказки читать я ему не советую, потому что в них используется язык, который в настояще время взрослыми людьми не употребляется. Его уровень русского: средний.

Посоветуйте какой-нибудь источник текстов, желательно доступный онлайн?

Comment: Все зависит от вашего уровня. 

Comment: >Посоветуйте онлайн-набор текстов для изучающего русский язык?

**Graduate**, напишите подробнее о себе. Вы в России живете? Родители - русскоязычные? 

Есть миллионы людей за пределами России с некоторым знанием русского языка. Например, у кого-то мама - русская, уехала из России за границу, вышла там замуж.

Comment: @Nikolja: Я обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пусть читает современные сказки - Эдуарда Успенского, например, или Льва Кассиля. Можно подыскать авторов, у которых много хорошей разговорной речи: Сергей Довлатов, Виктория Токарева, Венедикт Ерофеев и т.д. Из классики: Пушкин "Повести Белкина", рассказы А.П.Чехова.

Answer (score 1):

Пускай начинает с таких диалогов. Когда уровень поднимется, пускай смотрит фильмы. Разговорную речь это точно улучшит. [Диалоги на русском для иностранцев](http://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?from=yandex.ru%3Byandsearch%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=&etext=518.JXU_iMtxU4ph0m-4lzHcnxQwcTzpiDJFiWd7oq2WItqlL6aqOO6S9_hX4lgjUmPotwLadN5q5jv9OB2GZ8JkYJJPfjDbRdMTHvuopMOPIS-zeXxXUQlYmco3cxv_3XTuGDCr8jrEKKSGa9Sn6w-NLqyxFldgy7Yfj1Lxfr7csxtKmJyxDwUpVMsdVUlIoV4c3PhSFORv8WG52vp7V87Ptw.a194f893f27477274d755966e872623f2b7d58e0&uuid=&state=AiuY0DBWFJ4ePaEse6rgeAjgs2pI3DW99KUdgowt9XsGes-COYeAtjuEaMUoBSHPmSAtnX-FpOm618erS_aKmJpRVtq9I5UIwBoGSCNnncC0wtptpWtotg8FZWVPOEMLHYTnGFlAEY8Ck_OndzLMZbKNaIo0LgrHh0oE2QgrZhPm2fGxiu2e9KC3Q5eVFY3XuSO5fg3phCAkXf0waWc7R1xSOWWDIkER0nSDvaD2zivF1pLc08KYRmHjP2kowtVKuU7Gjl9BVEk&data=UlNrNmk5WktYejR0eWJFYk1LdmtxcEc5TE5tcUFaNGt5ZXFDVHBIWkh1TXhWZFVHNUFIR0hCN2lGV09TcTZhRG5qN3FzaFNwNDNIbUtPZzN3emU3Wkhoc2N5SUxBVjMzYmVzcE4yRjI3ZzdYUW1TakpCVnNheG9qMVZCS2h5alRGRklUYm5UeFlKaw&b64e=2&sign=3f61469a19cea38d3dcf7bbc350f7bcf&keyno=0&l10n=ru&cts=1416840211076&mc=5.393884216149484)

Answer (score 1):

Фильмы с субтитрами, если позволяет "средний уровень", в сочетании с занятиями грамматикой.

Comment: Присоединюсь к этому совету. 

Если ваш знакомый, @Graduate, уже владеет русским языком на **среднем** уровне, то чтобы перейти на более высокий уровень понимания, нужно изучать не просто **слова**, но и **культуру**. Научиться понимать тонкости значений, игру слов, юмор. 

.

Я бы посоветовал ему осилить фильмы Гайдая, *"чтобы расти над собой"*. :-)

Очень желательно, чтобы эти фильмы он смотрел не сам, а вместе с каким-то русским человеком. В этих фильмах полно крылатых фраз из современной русской речи.

Comment: А **для начала**, можно найти в Интернете и посмотреть известные ему **американские фильмы** в хорошей русской озвучке. Там могут быть субтитры на русском и английском языках. А если изначально нет субтитров, то можно найти в Интернете и добавить.

.

**Современное** русское кино -- смотреть с осторожностью. Потому что начиная пожалуй с конца 80-х и точно с начала 90-х -- *"страшно далеки они от народа"*! ОЧЕНЬ *"на своей волне"*... Так что, пожалуй лучше не смотреть, за редким исключением.

Comment: По моему скромному мнению, больше всего хороших фильмов на русском языке можно найти, начиная от второй половины 50-х и до начала/середины 80-х. Эпоха Хрyщёвa и Брeжнeвa, в общем.

Опять-таки, надо чтобы вашему знакомому кто-то знающий посоветовал что-то приличное. Потому что неинтересных фильмов и тогда тоже было немало.

Comment: Больше всего хорошего текста в фильмах, снятых по пьесам. Например, фильмы Марка Захарова по Шварцу и Горину, многие фильмы Эльдара Рязанова, экранизации классики.
Неплохо еще учить хорошие стихи и песни.